# Eclipse - easy access to frequently used folders?

Tags: eclipse

Does anyone know of a plugin for Eclipse to use 'favorite folders' in a project ?

There are maybe 2 or 3 folders inside my project (of 1000+ folders) that I regularly switch between. It's really a drag to use the scrollbar in the Project Explorer each time to get to the right folder, since some of them are 5 levels deep in the directory tree.

It would be VERY nice to have a separate small panel below the Project Explorer to access these frequently used folders...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At this point, looks like https://stackoverflow.com/a/12365878/470838 is more relevant than this answer.

Note quite what you want, but Eclipse allows you to [bookmark files](http://www.luisdelarosa.com/2005/02/16/eclipse-tip-use-bookmarks-to-track-important-places-in-your-code/). You could use this to bookmark a file in each directory and then use the Bookmarks view to move around from there.

Comment: see @Oben Sonne's answer below for how to make it work with bookmarks

Comment: Well, I am not really astonished by this feature (f.e. you can't make bookmarks for directories), but at least it exists.

Comment: Maybe we can update the answer, Eclipse allows since a long time to bookmark also folders.

Answer (score 10):

Eclipse now allows to bookmark folders -- the [corresponding bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=330590) is fixed.

When you select a folder in the tree, the add option might not appear in the context menu, but it does appear in the application menu at *Edit -› Add Bookmark*.

However, while the folder then is listed in the bookmarks view, nothing happens when it gets clicked. One has to right-click the bookmark and then select *Show in...* to get the actual folder focused in the navigator/explorer. IMHO it is better (i.e. more robust) than the workaround using file-bases bookmarks, but it still could be improved (e.g. without the context menu extra clicks to switch to a bookmarked folder).

Comment: Yes, but you can't jump to a bookmarked directory by a doubleclick... it must "right click -> show in -> package explorer"... I would be so glad to find the person who "invented" this wonderful feature and ask him, what he thought as he wrote it so...

Answer (score 5):

This topic may be old, but I think this solution is good enough

Use "Working set" feature to group files/folders you need into a working set

### Create a working set

1. Open a view like Project Expoler, Navigator or PHPExplore (if you
   have PDT) or Package Explorer (if you are a java coder)
2. Click "View Menu" (small triangle icon) at top-right of the view opened
3. Select "Select Working Set..."
4. Choose "Selected Working Sets" option
5. Click button "New"
6. Pick a type you need, click next, give it a name (eg: **MyBookmark**) and choose any
   project(s)/folder(s)/file(s) shown under "Working set content" to include in **MyBookmark** and finish

### Open/edit/close a working set

- To open a working set (**MyBookmark**), follow steps 1 -> 4 above and
  check the checkbox named **MyBookmark**, click OK. Now the view display only contents of **MyBookmark**
- To edit **MyBookmark** contents click "View Menu" and select "Edit Active Working Set..."
- To close current working set and back to original display click
  "View Menu" and select "Deselect Working Set"

Answer (score 2):

I would really recommend **[Mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/)** (a [task-focused interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task-focused_interface)) for this kind of workflow.

By defining the appropriate **[task context](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Mylyn/User_Guide#Context)**, you could switch to such tasks and see only the folders you need (no dragging involved) as opposed to see *everything*.

[image]

Comment: Mylyn is great!  However, I don't think that it solves the problem of setting up an initial task context to include your **most used** folders.

Each time I activate a brand new task, I would like to be able to have the folders that I most commonly work in to be automatically added to the task context, without having to copy them from another task.

Answer (score 1):

To add to VonC's answer:

### Adding files into Mylyn's current task context using Bash

Currently there are two main ways I have found to manually add certain files into the activated Mylyn task context when you activate a new task.  This works well for me because I *always* have a prompt open or [accessible at a keypress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yakuake).

1. In a bash prompt, run: `eclipse <file_to_add>`
2. With *Focus on Active Task* selected in Eclipse's *Project Explorer*...

   1. Run `touch <file_to_add>` (either create a new file, or update timestamp of existing file)
   2. In Eclipse, click on your project and press F5 to Refresh.  The file should show up.

The first one will open the file you want to work on in Eclipse, and it will show the file in the task context.  The second one forces Eclipse to see that the file was accessed, and it will add it to your task context.

### Setting up commonly used directories in Bash

To solve the problem of having to `cd` into your most commonly used folders all the time, use bash's built in directory stack feature.

Create a script (preferably in your personal [home bin](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=73520)) called `sh.init`

Add something like this to the file:

```
pushd ~/src/some/seldomly/used/path
pushd ~/src/some/less-seldomly/used/path
pushd ~/src/some/commonly/used/path
pushd ~/src/some/most-commonly/used/path
```

Make sure to `chmod +x sh.init`. (I added this into a function in my .bashrc myself that does a couple other things, but a separate script is probably easiest.)  Now run this script whenever you want to add these dirs into your directory stack, and end up in the last one.  There is a good tutorial on how to use these functions [here](http://www.safeer.in/2009/05/manipulating-bash-directory-stack.html) or in the [bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) ( Look for **dirs** under *Shell Builtin Commands* section).  You will always be in the directory on the **top** of the stack.  Here are some quick tips:

- Use `dirs` to display the stack  ( will display on one line.  **Top** = *left*, **Bottom** = *right* )
- Use `dirs -v` to display the stack in multiple lines with numbering ( makes top / bottom order make more sense graphically )
- To switch the top 2 directories, run `pushd`
- To cd into the third or fourth dir from the *left*, (effectively ***rotate*** the stack) use `pushd +2` or `pushd +3` respectively.
- These general rules apply when rotating the stack:

  - Numbering always starts from **0**
  - If counting **n** dirs from the *top* (left), use **+n**
  - If counting **n** dirs from the *bottom* (right), use **-n**
- Use `popd` to **pop** a directory off the stack, and cd into the ***new*** top dir on stack

  - Use `dirs +n` or `dirs -n` to display the **n**'th dir from the top (left) or right (bottom) of stack.
- Use `pushd <new_dir>` to push a new directory onto the stack (and cd into it)